# AJAX Validar usuario y contraseña php pdo con password_hash

Tags: php, ajax, mvc, pdo, login

tengo un problema a la hora de querer validar 3 opciones (1= validar que el numero de identificación digitado en el formulario exista en la base de datos, 2= validar la contraseña sea la misma que esta almacenada en la base de datos y 3= Validar que ambos casos anteriores sean verdaderos). El envió de los datos lo hago por AJAX para que este se encargue de mostrar las alertas dependiendo de su respuesta desde el controlador.

**Funcion por AJAX:**
En esta función enviamos los datos al método del controlador, donde su respuesta es: si! el indice del objeto que devuelve en el parámetro (res.identificacion ) es diferente de 1 muestra la alerta de que esa cédula no esta en la base de datos y así con la contraseña ingresada.

```
function ajax_send_formulario_login(){
url = javascript_URL + "login/entrar/";
var parametros = new FormData(document.querySelector('#form-login-send'));
ajax_async("POST", "", "json", url, parametros, function(res){
    if (res.identificacion != 1) {
            Swal.fire({
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'La cédula digitada no se encuentra en la base de datos..!'
            });
         return;
    }
    if (res.contrasena != 1) {
        Swal.fire({
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'La Contraseña digitada no es la correcta..!'
            });
         return;
    }
});
```

}

**Controlador que llega los parámetros:**
En este metodo comprobamos si el indice $validar_login['identificacion'] y $validar_login['contrasena'] sea igual a 1, me imprima lo que venga en ese array de  $validar_login

```
public function entrar()
{
    //Array de datos
    $array = $_POST;
    //Instaciamos el modelo
    $modelo_login  = new BolsaCaribe();
    $validar_login = $modelo_login->validate_user($array);
    // Validamos la cedula que exista
    if ($validar_login['identificacion'] == 1) {
        echo json_encode($validar_login);
    } else{ echo json_encode($validar_login);}

    if ($validar_login['contrasena'] == 1) {
        echo json_encode($validar_login);
    } else{ echo json_encode($validar_login);}
}
```

**Modelo:**
En este método del modelo es donde no estoy muy seguro de la lógica para poder obtener el resultado esperado, hago el SQL y como pueden ver cree un array con los indices de los parámetros para las respuestas en el controlador y posterior al ajax. en este espacio valido que el password que envió desde el formulado sea igual al que tengo en la base de datos, pero la verdad no me funciona, cuando ejecuto el programa, solo me valida la parte de la cédula. si existe me envía 1 como respuesta y si no 0, al parecer cuando intento validar que la password que dígito sea igual a la que tengo en la base de datos, esto me devuelve un valor null.

```
function validate_user($array)
{
    $sql = "SELECT pass_usuario, numero_identificacion FROM usuarios_bolsa WHERE numero_identificacion = :cedula";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $parametro = array(':cedula' => $array['cedula']);

    $stmt->execute($parametro);
    $resultado = $stmt->fetch();
    // Array que contiene los valores de la respuesta
    $resp = array(
                'identificacion' => 1,
                'contrasena' => 1);

    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
        if (password_verify($array['password'], $resultado->pass_usuario) == true) {
            return $resp;
        }
    } else{
        return array(
            'identificacion' => 0,
            'contrasena' => 0);
    }

}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar a solucionar este problema. saludos

Comment: Tienes un return en la respuesta del ajax antes de los if que nunca te dejará ejecutar las condiciones if

Comment: lo siento, lo deje porque estaba validando que los datos llegaran con un console.log antes de ese return

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres obtener los campos de un objeto como las propiedades de un objeto, debes pasarle como parámetro a él método fetch el valor PDO::FETCH_OBJ  http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php.